# Color white if background is black and vice-versa

Tags: less

I read about Properties as Variables in [less](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature#variables-feature-properties-as-variables-new-)

Now I like to have a h1-text-color depending of the background-color.

```
@black: black;
@white: white;
* when ($background = @black) > h1 {
  color: @white;
}
* when ($background = @white) > h1 {
  color: @black;
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work.

The processor (in java) drops me a:

```
org.lesscss.LessException: SyntaxError: expected condition in C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\temp\tmp8751667891323027624less.tmp on line 11, column 9:
10
11 * when ($background = @black) > h1 {
12   color: @white;

        at org.lesscss.LessCompiler.compile(LessCompiler.java:423)
        at org.lesscss.LessCompiler.compile(LessCompiler.java:330)
        at org.lesscss.LessCompiler.compile(LessCompiler.java:312)
```

Comment: The error says it all. The proper syntax in your case would be: `* > h1 when (@background = @black) `. but it's assuming `@backround` is a real variable you set elsewhere. If you are for properties than it will be `$background` - but note this must be property set in CSS class/ruleset (somewhere in the same scope of the same Less code, i.e. read the examples there). "Properties" in this case do not mean Less will some read property from an unknown HTML element of your pages (this is simply impossible).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Ah, it was a $ not a @, I am sorry.

Comment: Either way, did you expect for that code the Less to know the `background` property of the `*` element which is parent to `h1`?. If yes then no, it won't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
        <artifactId>lesscss</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
```

Resolves compatible version of less 1.7. The feature is only available in 3.0.

[dependency on github](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin)

Comment: Also notice there's [`contrast` function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-contrast). E.g. `color: contrast($background);` will do the same in one line. (For non-color values v3 also has `if` function).